# Search query on Okta Users API

Tags: okta

I am trying to run a query in our instance of okta using postman.  The problem I am running into is that Postman says it has syntax errors.  Exact wording "Invalid search criteria.".  Here is a partial copy copy of my structure:

```
{
    "id": "00u1c9lvdpsArq00J0h8",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "created": "2017-02-28T18:55:23.000Z",
    "activated": "2017-02-28T18:55:24.000Z",
    "statusChanged": "2017-02-28T18:55:24.000Z",
    "lastLogin": null,
    "lastUpdated": "2017-05-01T10:30:59.000Z",
    "passwordChanged": null,
    "profile": {
      "login": "lynn@enterthepicture.com",
      "firstName": "Lynn",
      "lastName": "Harvey",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "email": "lynn@enterthepicture.com",
      "secondEmail": null,
      "primaryPhone": "4169329890"
    },
    "credentials": {
      "provider": {
        "type": "ACTIVE_DIRECTORY",
        "name": "idm.sni"
      }
    },
```

The query I am trying to run is `{{url}}/api/v1/users?search=credentials.provider.name eq "idm.sni"`

If anyone has any suggestion I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

The search expression needs to be URL encoded, an example can be found here: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#list-users-with-search

So in your example, the request URL would need to look like `{{url}}/api/v1/users?search=credentials.provider.name%20eq%20%22idm.sni%22`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, you can't search on `credentials.provider.name`

Comment: it would be great if you'd explain why...